# Windows Workflow, WCF Ria services & Silverlight Example

Tags: workflow-foundation, wcf-ria-services

I'm looking for an example of using Windows Workflow as a server-side 'business logic' layer, with WCF RIA services handling the communication to and from a Silverlight UI.  Been googling for examples, but can't seem to find any.  If anyone can point me to a resource, I'd sure appreciate it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This would be an ideal place to start:

[Get Started with WCF RIA Services by The Silverlight Team](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/advanced-techniques/wcf-ria-services/get-started-with-wcf-ria-services)